# Select all the customer to check if the customer is loyal to one brand and product

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table , where I need to find the customer who is loyal/every time bought one brand and one product chocolate . The customer id should not have bought same brand with different product .

Customer Table

| Customer _id | Product | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Chocobix | Cadbury |
| 235 | Chocobix | Cadbury |
| 123 | 5 star | Cadbury |
| 456 | Kikat | Nestle |
| 235 | Chocobix | Cadbury |
| 456 | Chocobix | Cadbury |
| 432 | Milky bar | Nestle |

From the above sample table we can figure out that customer id 235 is loyal because that customer every time bought same product and brand .

I tried with union, intersection , having and group by . But not getting proper results  .

Comment: Either GROUP BY with HAVING. Or NOT EXISTS.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.customer_id
from
(
   select customer_id
   from Customer 
   group by  customer_id, product, brand
) t
where (select count(*) from Customer c where c.customer_id = t.customer_id group by c.customer_id )  > 1
group by t.customer_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want customers that have only purchased one product/brand combination.  One way of saying that is that the aggregation on `customer_id`/`product`/`brand` returns only one row for that customer.  Based on your example data, you also seem to want at least two purchases.

This is easily expressed using window functions:

```
select customer_id, product, brand
from (select customer_id, product, brand,
             count(*) as cnt,
             count(*) over (partition by customer_id) as num_product_brands
      from t
      group by customer_id, product, brand
     ) cpb
where cnt > 1 and num_product_brands = 1
```